# Select picker is not working with simple html select?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using select & selectpicker-plugin for states and places values. State values are loaded properly in select option and on select change select picker value(places) should be displayed. On web pages, place values are not visible and when i check with browser debug Elements, i can see the places values are loaded.
What is the cause that its not visible on webpage?

When I remove `selectpicker` from class,

```
  <select class="form-control" id="selectplaces">
  </select>
```

I can see the values are loaded and visible on web page

Comment: Live example needed!

Comment: is there any error in developer console?

Comment: @Mr. X, how to create live example as I am using MYSQL as database

Comment: @Prateik Darji, there is no error in code.

Comment: By simulating your code, go to `jsfiddle.net` add a `select option` with static data, and include those plugin you used by `cdn` and share it here. that's it!

Comment: Have you ever tried, two selectpicker with dependency of second on first.

Comment: Just to help you to use jsfiddle, here is a starting fiddle with bootstrap-selectpicker: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/ue44uk9b/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't use `.selectpicker('refresh')` method to refresh bootstrap-selectpicker element after loading new values (places).

Here is a snippet with two bootstrap-selectpicker connected together:

```js
$('#selectstates').on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
  var v = $(e.target).val();
  console.log("selected value:", v);
  switch (v) {
    case "us":
      addOptions('#selectplaces', ['New Jork', 'Chicago']);
      break;
    case "it":
      addOptions('#selectplaces', ['Rome', 'Venice']);
      break;
    case "de":
      addOptions('#selectplaces', ['Berlin', 'Hamburg']);
      break;
    default:
      $('#selectplaces').selectpicker('val', []);
  }
});

function addOptions(id, arr) {
  $(id).empty();
  var opt = $('<option data-hidden="true">select a place...</option>');
  $(id).append(opt);
  for (var i in arr) {
    opt = $("<option/>").val(arr[i]).html(arr[i]);
    $(id).append(opt);
  }
  $(id).selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label>States:</label>
<select class="selectpicker" id="selectstates">
  <option data-hidden="true">select a state...</option>
  <option value="us">USA</option>
  <option value="it">Italy</option>
  <option value="de">Germany</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label>Places:</label>
<select class="selectpicker" id="selectplaces">
</select>
```